# Professional Object Tracking Solution

Tags: image-processing, tracking, object-detection

I want to build a video based tracking software. I can manage the control and display quite easily but the actual object tracking in a video stream is very difficult (color tracking is not an option).
Solutions like openCV would probably require a very long learning curve which I can't afford ATM.
Are there professional packages which expose a simple API for object tracking? C# and C++ are the preferred languages but other would be fine as well. Price is also less of an issue.

Comment: Nice paper here http://coewww.rutgers.edu/riul/research/papers/pdf/trackmo.pdf

Comment: Thanks @belisarius but this is the opposite of what I want. I am sure I can do all the research but my time is short and I need the software package with the convenient API.

Comment: That is why I posted a comment and not an answer. The link is intended for someone else coming here in the future researching the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB provides tracking functionality. Please check out the following examples:

- [Tracking a face](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html)
- [Tracking multiple objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html)

Generally, a lot depends on the specific problem you are trying to solve. Is the camera moving or stationary? Do you need to track a single object or multiple objects? Does your object have a distinctive color or texture? Does your object move in some predictable way?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dima. As you can see from the date the project for which the question was asked for was discarded almost 2 years ago.

Comment: @Shy, well, I saw that the question was asked 2 years ago... :) I had no way of knowing whether or not this project is still active. In any case, if you ever need to do tracking again, or if anyone else is looking for information on tracking, this answer may be useful.

Comment: As a gesture of good will to all, I will mark it up (I couldn't honestly mark it as the answer since I haven't tested it)

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenTLD](https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD). It tracks almost anything, but at a time, track only one thing. And code is in matlab.